# Atualizar filho sem excluir registro utilizando JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho uma entidade que possui uma lista dentro dela. Essa lista é do mesmo tipo que a entidade dela.
Ex:

```
public class Aluno(){

   List<Pessoa> responsaveis = CollectionsBuilder.createDefaultArrayList();
}
```

Quando atualizo o aluno, removendo um responsável, utilizando a notação `CascadeType.ALL`, ele não atualiza o responsável, ou seja, não remove dele a referência para aluno.

Não posso utilizar `orphanRemoval = true` pois não posso excluir o registro do pai, somente remover o vínculo entre pai e filho.